# Range of multivariable function... a projection?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a two-variable function $f$, would I be mistaken if I said that a visual representation of its domain is merely the projection of its surface in 3D onto the xy-plane?

Also, can domain in some way be related to a contour or a level curve, or do they have little to do with each other?

Comment: I guess you mean a real-valued function of two real variables? So $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function $f : X \longrightarrow Y$, then it's graph is a subset of $\Gamma \subset X \times Y$, which is: $\Gamma = \{ (x,f(x) \in X \times Y : x \in X \}$ then by definition, the first projection of the graph is $X$ which is the domain.

I don't get your second question.